# How to return a string 3 characters long after the third '+' sign in snowflake?

Tags: sql, regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a long string of setups and descriptions mixed together as one object, the string contains several `::` and `+` characters among other things, may or may not have spaces, I'm trying to return the 3 characters after the third plus sign, i have tried using the expression below but returns null

```
regexp_substr(OBJECT1,'+\\w\\)',1,3,'e',1)
```

Do you know what i have been doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: do you have sample data and expected outputs?  That'd help.  I'd probably lean towards using a SPLIT_PART() function over a regex, personally.

Comment: `+` has special meaning in regular expressions, you have to escape it to match it literally. Why do you have `\\)` at the end of the regexp?

Comment: @Barmar, i originally had \\w(\\W there because i was unsure if id found spaces but i forgot to delete in here, sorry about that. following up on your answer, for learning purposes haha i tried to use \ to escape after the + but i couldnt make it work either, is there something else to be done there? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `split_part()` would look something like this:

```
select left(split_part('1+12+123+4567','+',4),3);
```

result: 456